# Mysql procedure results in error 1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i've been using pl/sql for a while.. And i'm bit confused about the variables in mysql procedure thing.

I'm trying to create a procedure, and I can't get it to compile :(

Error i got:
[image]

Heres the full code

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `NewProc`()
BEGIN


SET @city = FLOOR(RAND() * 5);
SET @uid = 3948;
SET @alive = (select alive from users where id = @uid);
SET @thread_id = 2950;
set @post_content = "AAAAOOOAAA! Jeg er i ";

if (@alive = 1) THEN        

    # Move NPC over to a random city
    UPDATE users set city = @city where id = @uid;

    # post a post on the forum thread
    INSERT INTO forum_posts (
        author,
        thread,
        creationdate,
        content,
    ) values (
        @uid,
        @thread_id,
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
        @post_content

    );


END IF;




END;;
```

Anyone of you geniusens that see what I've done wrong :)?

Comment: The error is almost exactly where the message says: `content,
    ) values`

Comment: whew. that was it.